# skip array results if condition repeated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The `articles.facets['date']['terms']` have this array:

```
[{"term"=>13, "count"=>4}, {"term"=>12, "count"=>1}]
```

I would like print only once this text "More than 10 years" if there is more than one element of the array that meets the requirement of being over 10 years old

```
<% articles.facets['yearsexperience']['terms'].each do |facet| %>
  <% if facet['term'] > 10 %>
    "More than 10 years"
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting now 2 times the same text:

```
"More than 10 years" 
"More than 10 years"
```

Comment: why don't you adapt your facet if you only need to know > 10 years?

Comment: This is my facet with tire `must { range :years_of_experience, { gt: 10 } }`. What is your suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F). It accepts a block which it invokes for each element in the enumerable, and returns true if the block returns `true` for *any* elements in the array:

```
<% if articles.facets["yearsexperience"]["terms"].any? { |t| t['term'] > 10 } %>
  More than 10 years
<% end %>
```

Comment: +1 because it's right but the issue lies in the underlying logic

Answer (score 0):

You can use break to get out of the .each context:

```
<% articles.facets['yearsexperience']['terms'].each do |facet| %>
  <% if facet['term'] > 10 %>
    "More than 10 years"
    <% break %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```